# STM32 program ATMega

Tags: atmega, stm32, programmer, stm32f0

Is it possible to program HEX file from STM32 to ATMega 328 ? I can think of some Serial communication, but I don't know whether is it possible to do on tiny STM32F0 series or it needs more powerful STM32.

It will probably be required boot loader support on ATMega chip for Serial programming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPI to perform ISP on a AVR MCU. The exact steps and connections required are detailed in the "Memory Programming" section, "Serial Downloading" subsection of the ['328 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) as well as in [AVR910](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0943.pdf). I recommend that you implement a known protocol such as that described in [AVR109](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc1644.pdf) so that your programmer works with existing tools.

Comment: I was originally thinking of creating something like embedded system where ATMega would do some low level calculations for STM32 and STM32 would have access to load a new program into it. It would not have direct access to any other programmers.